EU compensation for a cancelled flight following ATC restrictions for an aircraft earlier in the day
I'm interested in your suggestions whether it's worth arguing about in the following situation when the airline denied EU compensation.
I was flying an evening flight with easyJet from GLA to AMS. Around 7 hours before the planned departure, the flight was said to be delayed by 30 minutes. 5 hour before the departure - delayed by 1 hour. 3 hours before - by 2 hours and eventually 1,5 hour before the departure it was cancelled. The aircraft was already delayed on an earlier route, it flew with delay on a SPU-AMS route, but then the whole AMS-GLA, GLA-AMS route was cancelled. The reason given was ATC restrictions.
I submitted an EU compensation claim which got rejected with the following explanation:

(...) as your flight needed to be cancelled for reasons outside of our control, unfortunately we’re unable to offer you compensation as well.
To further explain what happened on the day; an earlier flight air traffic control restrictions substantially regulated the air space, which resulted in long delays to flights as aircraft waited for air space ‘slots’ to operate, sometimes for several hours. This delay pushed your flight into the curfew at Amsterdam (AMS) which meant we had no option but to cancel your flight. We do take reasonable measures to avoid delays and cancellations to our flights by having replacement crews and spare aircraft available in our network. However, in the circumstances, these options would not have helped as your flight was cancelled due to air traffic control restrictions.

I understand that the ATC restrictions are outside of airline's control and that the airport's curfew makes it impossible for them to land the airplane that is delayed until well into the night. I could however imagine - and the airline rep mentioned that literally in their reply - that sending a replacement crew and aircraft on time to make the AMS-GLA-AMS flights would solve the issue, given that the delay was known several hours before the departure and AMS is easyJet's hub. Therefore, I am questioning the argument in the circumstances, these options would not have helped as your flight was cancelled due to air traffic control restrictions - in my view these options would have helped, but the airline chose to blame it on the ATC because it's an easy way out for them without providing compensation.
Can anyone answer if the airline is in the right refusing compensation or is my reasoning sound and worth arguing further with the airline?

IDK how quickly airlines can get a replacement aircraft and crew together, file paperwork etc, or what time your flight was scheduled to depart. However, with the ATC delays would even a replacement aircraft have been able to get to GLA and return to AMS before the curfew (which is 23:00h local time)?

Thanks for suggesting the duplicate question. Indeed, the case seems similar and similarly ambiguous.

Nitpick: AMS is not “EasyJet’s hub”, it’s just one of its many bases. While they are more likely to have spare aircraft/crew there, it’s by far not a guarantee, especially if wide scale disruption affected many flights (they don’t have dozens of aircraft and crew just sitting around). Also what is the timeline of the ATC restrictions compared to that pair of flights?

@AdamMichalik Yup. :-( No surprise there. The ambiguity benefits the airlines.

@jcaron Fair point and I do feel somewhat sympathetic to the airline on this occasion, I understand how a disruption which is not their fault cascades throughout the day. I was trying/hoping to argue that they could have done more to stop the cascade. The aircraft was already delayed by 1h30 for the flight departing at 12:35 CEST. The GLA-AMS flight was at 20:45 CEST.
